# Chatroom log in with no 3rd party libraries

Tags: java, performance, server

So, I'm creating a chatroom with no 3rd party libraries and currently I'm logging people in like this:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        this.running = true;
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1000);
        while (this.running) {
            this.threadPool.execute(new InfoGrabber(ss.accept()));
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Listener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private class InfoGrabber implements Runnable {

    private final Socket socket;

    public InfoGrabber(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            Object obj = ois.readObject();
            if (obj instanceof ClientInformation) {
                clientManager.addClient(new ClientClass((ClientInformation) obj, new ClientConnection(socket, ois, ((ClientInformation)obj).getUUID())));
                System.out.println("Client connected");
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Listener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?
Git for more context https://github.com/CjStaal/ChatRoom
I have a `systemQueue` set up which takes `SystemMessage` which is a string, and an object. I want to be able to make this better, and have it more encapsulated and modular to allow easier maintainability and expandability. In the long run, I want it to be able to authenticate against a SQL database.

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of missing links in your code, which makes a review hard to do.

Your ServerSocket code at first glance looks OK, but it is actually broken.

> ```
>     this.running = true;
>     ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1000);
>     while (this.running) {
>         this.threadPool.execute(new InfoGrabber(ss.accept()));
>     }
> ```

You don't have a declaration for `running`. If it is a volatile boolean, then it will probably work. If it is not volatile, it'll possibly never work, depending on the setup. I would never recommend the use of volatile, though, so I would recommend an `AtomicBoolean`. Still, even with an atomic boolean, you may never exit your server loop because it only checks to see if it should stop after it has accepted a connection. The code will sit waiting on the `accept()` until something happens, even if the `running` is false. You need a different mechanism, or timeouts, on your code.

The actual socket you get is also badly handled. You create a thread to run the socket on, and you create an ObjectInputStream on the socket. This is OK, but you then schedule that on a thread which exits quickly... the `ClientClass` instance is registered on to the `clientManager`, but then no thread appears to be listening for more input from the client? Additionally, nothing has told the client that it is connected.

This code appears to be pretty new, and incomplete.

Comment: The thread is in ClientConnection, which is a part of ClientClass, to listen for incoming messages. I just had put the running to get it started. This is far from a complete application. later I'm going to add ways to control everything, but for now I'm just trying to get it up and running (which it is able to be run and it works. But it's so badly coded I want to know how to reengineer it to make it a lot better, in every term)

Comment: https://github.com/CjStaal/ChatRoom/blob/master/src/com/staalcomputingsolutions/chatroom/server/clientclass/ClientConnection.java

Here is the code for listening for more communication